# Not able to convert Mongoose find result into an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars.js

I want the result of this code to get converted into an array.

```
>User
  .find()
  .select("-_id services.location ")
  .lean()
  .exec(function(err,users){

    if (err) {

      console.log("Error Finding the users")

    } else {

      users=JSON.stringify(users);

      console.log("new:-",users)

      console.log(users)

      res.render('allroads1',{users:users})

    }

   })
```

The result  i am getting is :-

```
    [{"services":[{"location":[17.4374614,78.4482878]},{"location": [17.4020637,78.48400519999996]}]}]
```

I want the result to be in format of :-

```
    [
      "17.4374614",
      "78.4482878",
      "17.4020637",
      "78.484005199996"
    ]
```

My schema is something like array of Numbers:-location:[{type: Number}]. I am using handlebars as my template engine. ##

Comment: I'm not sure you can.  Why don't you use NodeJS and loop through the response to create your desired output array?

Comment: Can you provide a bit clearer example of the desired format? I can't see a way to get from your result and the target one.

Comment: @NickCaruso can you please guide me how to loop through them using NodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

if you format your initial response into an array then the following code should help do what you want, essentially we use map to get the values out and then concat and reduce to flatten the arrays.

```
var x = [[{"services":[{"location":[17.4374614,78.4482878]},{"location": [17.4020637,78.48400519999996]}]}]
        ,[{"services":[{"location":[17.4374614,78.4482878]},{"location":[17.4020637,78.48400519999996]}]}]
].map(function(obj) {
    return obj[0]['services'].map(function(obj){
        return obj['location']
    });
}).reduce(function(acc, val){
    return acc.concat(val);
}).reduce(function(acc, val) {
    return acc.concat(val);
});
console.log(x);
```

gives

```
[ 17.4374614,
  78.4482878,
  17.4020637,
  78.48400519999996,
  17.4374614,
  78.4482878,
  17.4020637,
  78.48400519999996 ]
```

so without the reduce and concatenate:

```
var x = [[{"services":[{"location":[17.4374614,78.4482878]},{"location": [17.4020637,78.48400519999996]}]}]
        ,[{"services":[{"location":[17.4374614,78.4482878]},{"location":[17.4020637,78.48400519999996]}]}]
].map(function(obj) {
    return obj[0]['services'].map(function(obj){
        return obj['location']
    });
});
console.log(x);
```

you get

```
[ [ [ 17.4374614, 78.4482878 ],
    [ 17.4020637, 78.48400519999996 ] ],
  [ [ 17.4374614, 78.4482878 ],
    [ 17.4020637, 78.48400519999996 ] ] ]
```

the response you got was pretty messy with two arrays of arrays of objects etc, but use map to get out of the arrays out of the objects, and since theres also an array of size 1 thats why theres the obj[0]

Comment: Yea! . This works but, i  have like numerous location pairs in my database, is there any way to loop through them efficiently instead hard coding them into the variable x.